# Kafka describe group commands showing discepency

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.10.2 and zookeeper 3.4.9 I am storing my offsets on Kafka broker. I am running 3 consumers on a topic having 5 partitions so in order to check the lags and all I ran the command

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --describe --group group1

So result for the first time is

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
topic1         1          669             670             1          consumer-1-9417e05b-1cf9-4f0f-b6cd-61effdd09456   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
topic1         4          616             617             1          consumer-3-9ba9b12e-d6c2-423f-93cd-313906a2559c   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-3
topic1         2          628             706             78         consumer-2-22263f3a-bb8a-4305-a1c8-fbae9f190dda   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
topic1         3          695             697             2          consumer-2-6abb5b02-3ee8-4fd2-ade3-e10e3ce7d06f   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
topic1         0          11433           39381           27948      consumer-1-30b79487-4de8-40a4-951c-02f25e8976fc   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-5-034e5889-dcc4-4cd1-975b-0d40a88899cf   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-5
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-3-c10d695e-e067-428f-b31a-3a5318d60ef3   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-3
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-4-090258c4-4d76-4cdd-8b62-f8fccf3ec097   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-4
```

and after 1 min running the same command displayed this result

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
topic1         1          345             678             333        consumer-1-9417e05b-1cf9-4f0f-b6cd-61effdd09456   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
topic1         4          620             622             2          consumer-3-9ba9b12e-d6c2-423f-93cd-313906a2559c   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-3
topic1         2          708             708             0          consumer-2-22263f3a-bb8a-4305-a1c8-fbae9f190dda   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
topic1         3          545             701             156        consumer-2-6abb5b02-3ee8-4fd2-ade3-e10e3ce7d06f   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
topic1         0          11433           39385           27952      consumer-1-30b79487-4de8-40a4-951c-02f25e8976fc   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-5-034e5889-dcc4-4cd1-975b-0d40a88899cf   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-5
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-3-c10d695e-e067-428f-b31a-3a5318d60ef3   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-3
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-4-090258c4-4d76-4cdd-8b62-f8fccf3ec097   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-4
```

How is this possible that before the current offset , lag and total offset (partition 1) were greater then the latter one.Please let me know if I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If a consumer uses `seek()` it can go backwards, and thus, `current offset` can become smaller.
- Not sure what you mean by "total offset"? If you refer to `log-end-offset` than this offset grows if new data get's written to the topic-partition (thus, it's independent of the actual consumer group).
- For `lag`: it's just the difference between `log-end-offset` and `current offset`. Thus, as `current offset` is smaller than before and `log-end-offset` is larger, it's larger, too.

Comment: Matthias - Thanks for replying I got your point. I am not using  seek at any point in my consumer code . And in one reading for topic partition 1 Current offset , log-end-offset and lag are displaying 669,670,1 and in the second reading its showing 345,678,333 how is this possible?